# Using Match in combination with Dates to see how many days are left

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good Morning,

I have the following right now:

| Column A | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| 21 Juli | row |
| Tomorrow | row |
| Tuesday | row |
| Wednesday | row |
| 23 Juli | row |

In the row, I want to find out how many days these dates are from today. With Tuesday and Wednesday I mean the upcoming one.

For the dates, I am already using:

```
=DATEDIF formula
```

This one is working correctly.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOw7fJO8c-ZgKPRTxWYjRW7ZpA9NDeC7Iw41wLGMZP8/edit#gid=0

Comment: `In the row, I want to find out how many days these dates are from today` and `D I sum up B + C` contradict each other. Which solution are you looking for? Also, please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Kaitlynmm569, I added an Example File.

What I want in essention is convert this data to dates (dd/mm/yyyy).

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation:

- Use [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) to check whether the source value is (A) `Tomorrow`, (B) a date (via [ISDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381?hl=en)), or (C) a weekday, and retrieve the difference of days in the correspondingly appropriate ways.
- (A) If the value is `Tomorrow`, that's easy enough, the result will always be `1`.
- (B) If the value is a date, use [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en) and [DATEDIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en) (I think you already got this).
- (C) If the value is a weekday, you have to create a list of such weekdays and use [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) to get the correponding week index. If the difference between this index and today's index (retrieved via [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en)) is negative, you'll have to sum 7 (since you want the upcoming weekday, not the previous one). Finally, get the difference between this value and today's weekday.

#### Solution:

Your formula could be something like this:

```
=IF(A3="Tomorrow",1,IF(ISDATE(A3),DATEDIF(TODAY(),A3,"D"),DATEDIF(TODAY(),TODAY()+IF(MATCH(A3,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)-
WEEKDAY(TODAY())<0,MATCH(A3,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+7,
MATCH(A3,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)-WEEKDAY(TODAY())),"D")))
```

[image]